# Setting up create method to automatically send welcome email causes, must pass a hash as an argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am creating a blog in Ruby on Rails with mailer capability. I would like to send a welcome email to new subscribers once they register. Unfortunately with my current code setup I receive a ("When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.") error! I have exhausted all of my brain power trying to rectify this problem, I would greatly appreciate any help any one can give me.

Here is my code: Subscribers controller

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_subscriber, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 respond_to :html

  def send_welcome
  NotificationMailer.welcome(params[:id]).deliver
    redirect_to new_subscriber_path
  end  

  def index
    @subscribers = Subscriber.all
    respond_with(@subscribers)
  end

  def show
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@subscriber)
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
    respond_with(@subscriber)
  end

  def edit
   @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
        NotificationMailer.welcome(@subscriber)
        redirect_to posts_path, notice: "You have successfully subscribed."

    else 
      render 'new'
    end 

  end

  def update
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
    @subscriber.update(subscriber_params)
    respond_with(@subscriber)
  end

  def destroy
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
    @subscriber.destroy
    respond_with(@subscriber)
  end

  private
    def set_subscriber
      @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_email
      @email = Subscriber.find(params[:email])
    end  

    def subscriber_params
      params.require(:subscriber).permit(:name, :email, :mobile)
    end
end

Notification_mailer - Welcome Method

    class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.notification_mailer.welcome.subject
  #
  def welcome(subscriber)
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber)
    @url = 'http://localhost:3000/posts'
    mail :to => "#{@subscriber.name} <#{@subscriber.email}>",
          :from => "myemail@gmail.com",
          :subject => 'Welcome to My Blog'
    end
```

Subscriber Model

```
    class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base

     validates :name, :email, presence: true
     validates :email, uniqueness: true
     validates :email, format: 
     { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }                
     end
```

Notification_mailer - view

```
<h1>NotificationMailer#welcome</h1>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
   </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Blog, <%= @subscriber.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully subscribed! <br>
    </p>
    <p>
   Please visit the site, read the post, and feel free to leave a comment,        
      just follow this link: <%= @url %>.   
     </p>
     <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings
in the development.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  #domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            'myemail@gmail.com',
  password:             'Password',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I am currently using rails 4, and have devise installed so I can logon as the site admin.

Thanks in advance for any help posted.

Update!

In order to get everything working I made a change to the notification_mailer and reconfigured the create method in the Subscribers Controller. The code is below:

notification_mailer

```
   def welcome(subscriber)
   @subscriber = subscriber
   @url = 'http://localhost:3000/posts'
   mail to:  "#{@subscriber.name} <#{@subscriber.email}>",
      from:  "wildgenius99@gmail.com",
      subject: 'Welcome to My Blog'
   end
```

Create Method
Subscriber Controller

```
   def create
   @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
   respond_to do |format|
   if @subscriber.save

    NotificationMailer.welcome(@subscriber).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 
    'Subscriber was successfully      created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscriber }
    else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @subscriber.errors, status:     
    :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end
```

Comment: Would you please also post the error message? Thanks!

Comment: You're passing the actual subscriber object to your mailer, then calling `Subscriber.new(@subscriber)` which is creating a new subscriber from your existing subscriber object.

Try replacing the line of `@subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber)` with `@subscriber = subscriber`.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit   Here is the error message:                                                          ArgumentError in SubscribersController#create
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Comment: @MikeManfrin I tried your suggestion, after the change the app still will not send an email.

Comment: What does your `new` form look like that feeds `subscriber_params` to `#create`. The error message could mean that the problem is here: `@subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)`

Comment: @Joseph between your suggestion and another article I was reading at the time, I was able to automatically send an email from the app. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you to every one that offered their time and expertise.

Comment: Please post the answer so that future people will know what you did to fix the problem. Thanks!